# Print single line on negative match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to identify rpm files which do not have a signature matching one I plan or do not have a signature at all. I'd like to print just the name of the rpm on a negative match. Example and ideal output below (my signature is 123456 in this example):

```
/a/folder/rpm_valid_signature.rpm:
    Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 123456: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (blah)
    V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 123456: OK
    MD5 digest: OK (blah)
/a/folder/rpm_invalid_signature.rpm:
    Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 000000: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (blah)
    V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 000000: OK
    MD5 digest: OK (blah)
/a/folder/rpm_unsigned_signature.rpm:
    RSA sha1 (MD5) (PGP) md5 NOT OK (MISSING KEYS: PGP#654321)
```

Ideally the output should list invalid matches, so: `/a/folder/rpm_invalid_signature.rpm` (nothing else). I'll use this in a find command and point the script at folders containing about 2k rpm files (either unsigned or signed with an invalid key).

Hope that makes sense, feels like a job for awk or sed but is made much more complex due to repetition in the files.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, have fun!  [ask] ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
signature=' key ID 123456:'  # or whatever should match
find /a/folder -type f -name '*.rpm' -exec grep -L "$signature" '{}' +
```

Comment: That's much more elegant than I had. Can I make this work with two strings? I'd like it to also print none matches containing "MISSING KEYS".

Comment: I've changed the question as I've realised it was vital to answering the question as two negative matches changes the requirement a lot.

Comment: I realised a single match would suffice. Thanks for your help, I really like this.

Comment: For two strings maybe just use `...egrep -L 'one_regex|another_regex'...` or some such.

Comment: Make sure to anchor the regexp. As written that would match `hockey ID 123456789`.